# Are there any intrinsic benefits to leveling up?

Tags: awesomenauts

As opposed to most MOBA style games, increasing your health in Awesomenauts appears to be mostly reliant on buying specific health upgrades. Additionally, you purchase abilities (and upgrades) via money, not levels. In fact, nearly everything seems to be based on the amount of money that you've gained as opposed to character levels.

For example: since you can't (that I know of) see your actual HP numbers, there's no easy way to determine if the simple act of leveling up gives you any additional HP.

So I'm wondering what exactly happens when your character levels up (in a round)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of Patch 2.6 (released August 28, 2014), the old Solar-based level system was removed**, possibly due to the fact that it didn't do anything besides give an approximate amount of Solar a character had collected.

However, **[a new leveling system](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Experience_System) was introduced in Patch 2.13 (released December 2, 2015)**, with levels being gained by killing neutral and enemy units and structures instead of directly through Solar gain. Experience is shared among an entire team, and every level a team gets increases the health, damage, and regen of the team's players, and the health and damage of the team's droids.

Answer (score 4):

People in [this discussion](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2853761) definitely believe there's no intrinsic benefit to leveling up. It also seems notable that even your level is based directly on money: you gain a level for every 100 Solar you earn, so someone's level still will give an idea of how strong they are likely to be.